# Can I compute closest split pair of points where distance is strictly less than delta

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I've been studying the closest pair algorithm lately and I found this to be an extremely good and intuitive resource: http://serverbob.3x.ro/IA/DDU0221.html. It is also explained in section 33.4, "Finding the closest pair of points" of *introduction to algorithms*, third edition  by CLRS.

I understand why I'd need 7 comparisons for a non pairwise distinct set of points and only 5 otherwise (33.4-2). Both of them follow from the fact that I can fit only 4 points, at least Delta away from each other, on a Delta x Delta box.

What I've been wondering though, is if I could trim the number of comparisons down to 3 if I included only points strictly less than Delta away from the middle line, in the middle Delta x 2 Delta strip. The reasoning is that I already have a pair of points Delta away from each other from the recursive calls, I only need points less than Delta and I can only fit 2 points Delta away from each other AND less than Delta from the middle line on each side.

Have I missed something or can I really just compare the 3 following points of every point in a middle strip only containing points strictly less than Delta from the center?

**Edit:**
I have started a bounty for a very similar question on stack overflow also and we have come up with a very interesting discussion there. So I'm linking it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079934/can-i-compute-closest-split-pair-of-points-where-distance-is-strictly-less-than). We've also started a very insightful chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186592/discussion-between-serggr-and-danilo-souza-moraes).

Comment: I just tried the link and it's working. I think it's a chapter of CLRS

Comment: All of https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/serverbob.3x.ro, https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/serverbob.3x.ro.html and https://isitdown.site/api/v2/serverbob.3x.ro show the site serverbob.3x.ro is down for the last 10 mins.

Comment: A variation of this question, [which asks whether we can do with 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079934/can-i-compute-closest-split-pair-of-points-where-distance-is-strictly-less-than) is posted on stackoverflow with a bounty as well.

Comment: I asked the same question on stackoverflow to see if I could draw more attention to it. I set a bounty on both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you have observed, we can just compute pair of points whose distances are strictly less than $\delta$ in the "combine" step of the "divide-conquer-combine" algorithm, where we examine the minimal distance between the points to the left and the points to the right.

However, it is not enough to just compute the next 3 points.

---

[image: Picture from section 33.4 of CLRS, third edition]

The above graph, taken from CLRS, illustrates the original argument for 7 in the case of non-pairwise distinct points and for 5 in the case of pairwise distinct points. For the sake of clearer explanation, assume the central line $l$ is the vertical axis and $\delta=\delta_L=\delta_R=1000$. Let the strip consist of the area between the line $x=1000$ and $x=1000$, excluding those two lines. This strip contains only the points that are strictly less than 1000 away from the central line $l$. Suppose all distinct points in the strip in the ascending order of vertical coordinate are $s_0, s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4$.

Suppose we have verified that $d(s_0,s_i)\ge1000$ for $i=1,2,3$. Can we conclude that there is no point $s$ such that $d(s_0,s)<1000$?

No. It might happen that
$$\begin{align}\\
s_0&=(79,0)\\
s_1&=(-921,1)\\ 
s_2&=(999,500)\\  
s_3&=(-999, 998)\\  
s_4&=(79, 999)
\end{align}$$

Note that $d(s_0, s_4)= 999<1000$. In fact, $d(s_i,s_j)\gt1000$ for all $i$ and $j$ except $d(s_0, s_4)$.
$$\begin{align}
d(s_0, s_1)&=\sqrt{1000001}  \\
d(s_0, s_2)&=\sqrt{1096400}  \\
d(s_0, s_3)&=\sqrt{2158088}  \\
d(s_0, s_4)&=\sqrt{998001}  \\
d(s_1, s_2)&=\sqrt{3935401}  \\
d(s_1, s_3)&=\sqrt{1000093}  \\
d(s_1, s_4)&=\sqrt{1996004}  \\
d(s_2, s_3)&=\sqrt{4240008}  \\
d(s_2, s_4)&=\sqrt{1095401}  \\
d(s_3, s_4)&=\sqrt{1162085}  \\
\end{align}$$
So if we only compute the distance with the next 3 points, we will not find that shortest edge from $s_0$ to $s_4$ at the end of the algorithm.

The above counterexample shows that it is not sufficient to just compare 3 following points of every point in a middle strip only containing points strictly less than $\delta$ from the center line, even if we assume that all points are distinct.

Comment: Right after looking at the coordinates you provided, I noticed how wrong I was in my assumption that I can fit at most 2 points, δ away from each other and less than δ away from `l`. I thought that was the case because if I were to fit 3 points in the corners of a square of side δ and then started moving the 2 points on one edge closer to the 3rd point, then that 3rd point would be force out of the square to keep the minimum distance of δ. But that is not the case. The 3rd point could move towards the center of the edge, ultimately forming an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Do you think it would be fair to say that when implementing this algorithm, it would be slightly more efficient (not asymptotically though) to build the middle strip with points less than δ away from `l` just to avoid comparing points that we already know are at least δ away from each other? Most implementations of this algorithm on the internet build the middle strip with points less than or equal to δ from `l`.

Comment: Yes, your observation does improve the performance of the algorithm. In fact, the bigger improvement might comes from the fact that 4 is enough as said in the other question of your (I may write a proof for that fact). Once the dust is settle down, I suggest that you update [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem#Planar_case) to mention these two observations.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you have passed the bounty to [the question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079934) too early to a fundamentally flawed answer, although you can still switch to accept another answer.

Comment: According to CLRS, we can fit at most 8 points in a 2 x  rectangle and so we need 7 comparisons. What the other answer and yours helped me understand is that I can fit at most 3 points in a  x $\dfrac{\sqrt(3)}{2}$ rectangle, hence 6 points in a 2 x  rectangle, rendering a total of 5 comparisons if we can ensure the middle strip is constructed with points on the x axis strictly less than . I can safely get to this conclusion by simply using the same proof CLRS provided. I just need to prove the maximum possible number of points in the middle strip.

Comment: CLRS has proven that I need at most N-1 comparisons where N is the total number of points in the middle strip. What I did was come up with a way to ensure a lower upper bound of the total number of points in the middle strip by ensuring only points on the x axis strictly less than  make it to the middle strip. This is an improvement to the original algorithm, not a fundamental change. Have you been able to come up with a different proof of the total number of points? I would very much like to see it.

Comment: I did start playing with triangles on both sides of `l` and I have the impression that the 2 highest points on the y axis will always be farther away from the origin then the previous 4, just because of the shape of a triangle, but I'm still working on a proof. I've implemented this algorithm that compares up to 4 points next to the current point and I'm comparing the output against a naive implementation O(n^2) and it's already compared millions of points and not a single mismatch.

Comment: "it's already compared millions of points and not a single mismatch". Because 4 is enough, as I have said quite a few times here and there now. In fact, if you divide the $\delta\times2\delta$ into enough number of small squares, you may got a compute-aided proof of that fact.

Comment: You have repeated that statement many times, without an explanation or intuition for it. The closest I've gotten to improving the algorithm to less than 5 iterations shows that only 3 comparisons are necessary (I've also ran random comparisons millions of times without being able to produce a single mismatch). My intuition follows from the fact that if I have an equilateral triangle of side δ parallel to Y, then the 3rd point in ascending order of Y is δ away from the origin and doesn't need to be compared.  If I rotate this triangle 45 counter clock, then the 3rd point becomes the second

Comment: So I still think only 3 comparisons are necessary

Comment: "I still think only 3 comparisons are necessary". Have you checked the counterexample in my answer?

Comment: You are right. What I perceive to be a triangle with the base parallel to the Y axis isn't solely on the right. One of the points of the "base" is actually on the left. Interesting.

Have you come up with a proof yet?

Comment: I have simplified my proof for 4 points enough that it might not take too much time for me to present its outline. I will try to do it in the near future.

Comment: Ill be waiting then. I'm very excited for it